# How to retrieve a Lambda function's associated API Gateway methods with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I'm trying to write a Python script that lets you rename a Lambda function by copying all of the code and configuration to a new function. As part of that process, I want to take all of the API Gateway methods that point to the old function and redirect them to point to the new function.

Is there a way to accomplish this with boto3?

Comment: Have you considered moving your lambda and API gateway to CloudFormation? This would allow you for easy re-use and re-deployment of your infrastructure across different regions and accounts.

Comment: Yes, I plan to do so eventually. This is a stopgap solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable, but you have to have two clients for APIGateway.

Following the calls you can make for doing this:

1. [get_apis](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#id138) > gives all the APIs deployed, then further you can drill down to individual APIs using **get_api**
2. [get_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigatewayv2.html) > This gives you all the paths in the chosen rest API.
3. [get_integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-integration.html) >  Gives you something like below:

   ```
        {
            "type": "AWS_PROXY",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east1-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:myfunction/invocations",
            "credentials": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/myrole",
    ...
        }
   ```